# strptime format - Python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm currently working with an API that returns date in the following format:

```
d1 = '2015-06-25T18:45:24'
d2 = '2015-07-11T18:45:35'
```

So, to find the difference between two times, in days, I'm doing the following:

```
import datetime
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
print abs((d2-d1).days)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '2015-06-25T18:45:24' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'
```

I know I could just simply split the string in `'T'` and then convert, however is there an easy way to convert to such format to datetime object?

Comment: Where is the `.%f` in `2015-06-25T18:45:24`? Where is the `T` in your sample code (which exists in the error output)?

Comment: Change the second argument to `strptime` to actually match the input you're getting?

Comment: @deceze I had included the `'T'` on it ... my mistake was to have `.%f` on it.

Answer (score 1):

The `%f` does not apply in this case, and you need that `T` in your format:

```
dt_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, dt_format)
```